# Using lambda expression in List of Projects [ENVDTE]

Tags: c#, linq

Currently, I am getting a project by running a loop :

```
IList<Project> prjs = SolutionProjects.Projects();
Project p = null;
for (int i = 0; i < prjs.Count; i++)
{
    if (prjs[i].Name == "prj5")
    {
        p = prjs[i];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same using a lambda expression? 
Thank You.

Comment: -1 as the question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your loop, it looks like you are getting the Last item which matched the criteria, You may try [Enumerable.LastOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) which will return you the last itme or null, if none is found.

```
Project p  = prjs.LastOrDefault(r=> r.Name == "prj5");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SolutionProjects.Projects().LastOrDefault(x => x.Name == "prj5")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable.LastOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx)(),

```
var project = prjs.Where(c=>c.Name == "prj5").LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Project p = SolutionProjects.Projects()
                .Where(p=>p.Name = "prj5")
                .LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: 'Technically' it should be `LastOrDefault` ;p

Comment: Shouldnt `.Select` be `.Where`?